# Shared Columns behaving strangely

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a database with about a dozen shared view columns. When I make a change to the column value formula of the shared column, those changes do not appear when I preview the views that contain the shared column.

Here is what I have tried:
1. Shift-F9
2. Close and reopen database
3. Close and reopen Notes
4. Go to bed and check back in the morning.

It certainly appears that my code changes to the shared columns are being saved to all views because after saving the shared columns the "last modified" date on all views is updated to the time I saved the shared column. Also, if I change the shared column value formula to "blah" then that works: all views show "blah" for every document in the column. But as soon as I introduce any formula into the shared column value (for example @Text(@DocumentUniqueID) or a field value or any other formula) it reverts back to showing me the ORIGINAL values that were in the column--as it was when the shared columns were originally saved.

It's as though the columns can't be changed from whatever formula they were originally saved with, unless that formula is just plain text (eg "blah").

Does anyone have any insight? I hope I'm just making some dumb mistake. I'm very close to just trashing the shared columns and just building standard columns for all views.

Comment: Did you check the programmatic name of the column (last Tab of properties)? Probably it is the same as another shared column (probably copied). Try to change it (just remove the value, it will be repopulated), that might help...

Comment: Torsten- That is an excellent suggestion and I did not think of that, but I checked and my shared columns each have unique names (I don't think I used copy/paste when I created them). Interestingly, if I **change** that unique name in both the view and the shared column it does finally update the shared column to the new formula. For this application, I replaced shared columns with regular columns, because I needed to get it working right away. Thank you for the response and I will keep this in mind for future use of shared columns.